# How do you write a SQL query to find all the rows that has a float currency value like $15.34 in a nvarchar field

Tags: sql-server

How do you write a SQL query to find only the rows that has a float currency value **like $15.34** and **NOT round currency value like 15** in a nvarchar field.

Comment: if it is a float value then db column have does not contain `$` sign so you can just write `select * from tablename where colname = 15.34`

Comment: Select * from tablename where colname like '%.%', returns all the float values but I only want rows were its not a rounded dollar amount.

Comment: Float and currency are two different datatypes. You can't have a float currency. I think you mean, find rows that are not whole numbers. The best way to deal with this is to stop putting numeric values in varchar columns.

Comment: You are right but that's how it is now and I need to find all the rows that doesn't have a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a mix of numeric and non-numeric, this should work to return all decimal values that are not whole dollar amounts:

```
Select * from tablename 
where colname like '%.%' --Has a decimal (as in original query)
and colname not like '%.00' --Does not end with 00
```

Comment: This will give extra rows if they contain a `.` for any other reason aside from being used as a decimal point.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff true, but (s)he already stated that the `%.%` was working to return all decimal values.  If (s)he knows what could be in the column, no need to add extra complexity to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as

```
Select * from tablename where columnname = '15.34'
```

Comment: It depends if it has the '$'. It sounds to me like OP says it's a nvarchar. May have to use `LIKE '%15.34%'` instead of `= 15.34`

Comment: I assumed from "like $15.34" that it wasn't always going to be 15.34 but any currency value that isn't a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

I would strip the $ out, and check if it evaluates to a numeric or not, and use a `modulo` to be sure a remainder remains when divided by 1.

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (columnname NVARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO @TEST
SELECT '$15.34' UNION
SELECT 'ZERO' UNION
SELECT '$123.00'

SELECT *, CONVERT(MONEY,REPLACE(columnname,'$',''))
FROM @TEST
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(columnname,'$',''))=1
AND CONVERT(MONEY,REPLACE(columnname,'$','')) % 1 != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
Select * from Yourtablename where Yourcolumnname like '$15.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you want to find the rows having the `$` in them.

```
WHERE LOCATE('$',columname) <> 0
```

Second, you want to find the rows where the rest of the value in the column is a floating point number.

```
 AND CONVERT(REPLACE(columnname,'$',''),DECIMAL(10,2)) <> 0
```

That `CONVERT() <>0` pattern works because MySQL silently returns zero when you try to convert a nonnumeric value to a number.